# Doorkeeper OAuth provider with custom devise strategy (SSO)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth, devise, doorkeeper

I'm building multiple rails apps that shall be used by the same users. Therefore it would be nice to have a single sign on using OAuth.

At this point of time I got two different apps:

ID - which handles all the user stuff (name, avatar, email, authentication)
TEAM - should be able to use ID's users via OAuth

ID runs with doorkeeper and TEAM uses devise for authentication.

---

My problem is that if I want to login into team with my doorkeeper OAuth provider I do always get an invalid credentials error - and I just don't know what to do.

That's my setup:

ID

```
# config/routes.rb

# oauth2 sso
use_doorkeeper

namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    # another api routes
    get '/me' => "credentials#me"
  end
end


# controllers/api/v1/api_controller.rb
module Api::V1
  class ApiController < ::ApplicationController
    def current_resource_owner
      User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id) if doorkeeper_token
    end
  end
end


# controllers/api/v1/credentials_controller.rb
module Api::V1
  class CredentialsController < ApiController
    doorkeeper_for :all
    respond_to :json

    def me
      respond_with current_resource_owner
    end
  end
end
```

I added an application with the callback `http://team.dev/users/auth/doorkeeper/callback`.

TEAM

```
# gemfile
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-oauth2'


# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" } do
  get 'sign_out', :to => 'users/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
end


# lib/omniauth/strategies/doorkeeper.rb
require 'omniauth-oauth2'

module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Doorkeeper < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2
      # change the class name and the :name option to match your application name
      option :name, :doorkeeper

      option :client_options, {
        :site => "http://aubrey-id.dev",
        :authorize_url => "/oauth/authorize"
      }

      uid { raw_info["id"] }

      info do
        {
          :email => raw_info["email"]
          # and anything else you want to return to your API consumers
        }
      end

      def raw_info
        @raw_info ||= access_token.get('/api/v1/me.json').parsed
      end
    end
  end
end

# config/initializers/devise.rb
require File.expand_path('lib/omniauth/strategies/doorkeeper', Rails.root)

Devise.setup do |config|
  config.omniauth :doorkeeper, 'APP ID', 'APP SECRET'
end


# controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def doorkeeper
    oauth_data = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    @user = User.find_or_create_for_doorkeeper_oauth(oauth_data)
    @user.update_doorkeeper_credentials(oauth_data)
    @user.save

    sign_in_and_redirect @user
  end
end


# controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
end


# models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :omniauthable

  def self.find_or_create_for_doorkeeper_oauth(oauth_data)
    User.find_or_initialize_by_doorkeeper_uid(oauth_data.uid).tap do |user|
      user.email = oauth_data.info.email
    end
  end

  def update_doorkeeper_credentials(oauth_data)
    self.doorkeeper_access_token = oauth_data.credentials.token
  end
end
```

If I now try to authenticate using doorkeeper all I get is a invalid credentials error.

Hope somebody has a hint for me!